# Browser-Sync with Grunt get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browser-sync

I get [this error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjaz29y9be6k8o2/Screenshot%202016-03-31%2019.10.06.png?dl=0) when using browser-sync with grunt. Here's [my gruntfile.js](https://gist.github.com/lukashillebrand/93115877ae5fa361b8fc660c7995afa2) , and yes I've included the browser-sync snippet before the closing  tag.

Maybe something with DNS? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the proxy in the options worked for me: 'localhost/lukashillebrand'

Answer (score 0):

Check your system to see if anything is running on Port 8000. Also check your router to make sure that it doesn't forward that port. In your terminal run the following command. On a Windows machine you can use the services explorer.

```
netstat -an | grep 8000
```

Comment: No i have no port forwarded and I get any output in terminal my Apache Port is on 80. I've also tried that but with no luck…

Comment: Nope again nothing - But when I add: proxy: 'localhost/lukashillebrand/' to the grunt settings then browser-sync redirects me, but with the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in the console.